# Flutter: Add value to LIst triggers RangeError (index)

Tags: flutter

Via this function, I add that much DataRows the user chooses in the UI. What I want to do is that the choosen value of the first row is the first value of the "besetzungsList" and the choosen value of the second row is the second value of the List and so on. And if a new value in the first row is choosen I want to replace the value.

```
addAufgabe() {
    print(besetzungsList);
    if (aufgabe.text.isNotEmpty || zeit.text.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {});

      if (event != null) {
        ...
      } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < currentValue; i++) {
          aufgabenList.add(aufgabe.text);
          zeitList.add(zeit.text);
          dataTableRows.add(
            DataRow(
              cells: [
                DataCell(Text(aufgabe.text), onTap: () {
                  removeRow(i);
                }),
                DataCell(Text(zeit.text), onTap: () {
                  removeRow(i);
                }),
                DataCell(DropDown(
                  hint: "Wählen",
                  users: users,
                  besetzungsListChanged: (String value) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < dataTableRows.length; j++) {
                      setState(() {
                        besetzungsList[j] = value;
                      });
                    }

                    //  }
                  },
                  fromDropDown: (bool value) => fromDropDown = value,
                ))
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you remove an Element at i and add one at same index which is the cause.
You should do it the other way around...

```
besetzungsList.insert(i, value);
besetzungsList.removeAt(i + 1);
```

Comment: Actually I am talking about the else instruction, sorry. I edited my code snippet.

Comment: Okay the thing is if you are  refering an element  by its index it should be there already.. so inorder to add new elements  at index where  nothing is there, you should always use the add method or insert method

Comment: Yes, exactly. The problem is with add-function the order is not correct and I need the index of the value in the besetzungsList to be the same as the index of the dataTableRows..
So for example if I already have 4 values and I want to change them, then I need to replace the specific value. And I think with insert its kind of the same thing